# Efficiently compute parallel matrix-vector product for block vectors with FFTs?

Tags: algorithms, parallel-computing, matrices, numerical-algorithms, fourier-transform

Assume I have $P$ processors, each having a different vector $v_p$ of size $N$, $p=1, ..., P$. I learned in this [question/answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/88181/efficiently-compute-parallel-matrix-vector-product-for-block-vectors) that for computing the matrix-vector product 
$$w = (E\otimes I_N)v$$
in parallel, where $\otimes$ is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), $v = (v_1, ..., v_P)^T$ is the stacked vector consisting of all local vectors $v_p$, $E = (e_{pj})_{p,j}\in\mathbb{C}^{P\times P}$ some dense matrix and $I_N$ is the identity matrix of size $N\times N$, I can basically do $P$ parallel sums using binary trees.

$N$ is pretty large (say, $10^8$), in particular much larger than $P$ (which is only 10-100) and so large that $NP$ (the size of $w$ and/or all vectors $v_p$ together) does not fit into each processor's memory.

Depending on the application, the matrix $E$ could be a Fourier or [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix), i.e. computing 
$$w_p = \sum_{j=1}^P e_{pj} v_j$$
should be possible using an [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform). For each of the components of the vector $v_j\in\mathbb{R}^N$, the FFT would not change. Do I still have to do $N$ FFTs or is there a "block-wise" FFT idea/implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the case where $P=2$, for starters.  The FFT can be computed in a [divide-and-conquer fashion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm#The_radix-2_DIT_case), where first we compute the FFT of the even-numbered indices, then the FFT of the odd-numbered indices, and then combine them in a simple step (with a single layer of butterfly operations).

So, if the even-numbered indices are stored on one processor and the odd-numbered indices are stored on a second processor, then you could do this in parallel in a natural way, with the first processor doing the FFT on its own data, and the second processor doing the FFT on its own data; the final butterfly step requires only $\Theta(NP)$ data sent over the network.

If the data isn't partitioned that way, then the first step could be to send all the values at even-numbered indices to the first processor and the values at odd-numbered indices to the second processor, then do the above process.  In total it will require $\Theta(NP)$ data sent over the network and $\Theta(N \lg N)$ computation ($\Theta(N \lg N)$ computation at each processor to compute the FFT locally).

More generally, if $P$ is a power of 2, you can generalize these ideas in a similar fashion.  You send the data to the appropriate processor   ($\Theta(NP)$ data sent over the network), then compute the FFT locally at each processor ($\Theta(N \lg N)$ steps of computation at each processor), then combine them with $\lg P$ butterfly layers (requires $\Theta(NP \lg P)$ data sent over the network).

If $P$ isn't a power of two, you can pick the largest power of two that is smaller than $P$, and use that many processor (the remainder are left idle).

Comment: OK, this sounds reasonable, thanks! Now, what if I only have space for one or two vectors v on each processor?

Comment: Wait, the original Cooley–Tukey FFT algorithm you are referring to would work with complex numbers instead of vectors of complex numbers (as in my case). So, I'd have to do N FFTs instead of one to cover the whole vector, right? And why would the runtime of the FFT depend on N?

Comment: @RobertSpeck, the solution I mention only requires space for about 1-2 vectors on each processor, and it works with vectors of complex numbers.  You only do one FFT per processor (i.e., $P$ FFTs in total).  Doing a FFT on a vector of length $N$ takes $\Theta(N \lg N)$ time (on a single processor).  Perhaps I'm not understanding your comments; or maybe I've made some mistake I'm not seeing?

Comment: The thing is that the FFT is performed on P nodes, not N, right? We have P vectors and the sum is over P. Each vector, though has the length N.. this is weird, I know, and I hope I'm on the right track here.

Comment: @RobertSpeck, that's right. That's why we do $P$ FFT's, not $N$ FFT's.  Each processor individually does a FFT on a vector of length $N$, then you combine their results to obtain a result that is the Fourier transform of the original vector of length $NP$.  Perhaps it will be easiest to understand this by focusing first on the case $P=2$ and understanding how that works...

Comment: I see what you mean. I have to implement this in order to fully understand what is going on, but at least now I know WHAT to implement. Thanks for your patience!